# How to fix 'This branch is 1 commit behind master.'

Tags: git, github

I am trying to set up Github branches correctly and I notice that on GitHub, on my `dev` branch, it says `This branch is 1 commit behind master.`.

I have already tried the other stackoverflow questions about this none worked for me.

In VS Code, I have checked out my `dev` branch and if I run `git status`, then it says

```
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But GitHub console still tells me that `This branch is 1 commit behind master.`. I want the changes I have from `dev` to be uploaded to the `master` branch. The `dev` branch has everything I need, it is okay if it just overwrites the `master` branch.

I already tried doing this in my `dev` branch:

```
git add .
git commit -m "update"
git push origin dev
```

Please, what can I do? I have been stuck on this for hours!

Comment: Try the following steps while you've got your `dev` branch checked out: `git fetch origin`, then `git merge master`. This will bring any extra commits from master into your `dev` branch and may cause merge conflicts. Resolve any merge conflicts and then run `git push origin dev` to push your updated `dev` branch up to `origin`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: Great, I'll paste this into an answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following steps while you've got your `dev` branch checked out: `git fetch origin`, then `git merge master`.

This will bring any extra commits from `master` into your `dev` branch and may cause merge conflicts.

Resolve any merge conflicts and then run `git push origin dev` to push your updated and caught-up `dev` branch up to `origin`.